# How to Print PDF file without print preview in java

Tags: java, pdf, printing, dialog, preview

I generated a PDF file using JasperReports successfully; the creation of my PDF file is through a button trigger. After generating the file, I would like to print that PDF file in the printer without the PDF preview (Opening the PDF File then clicking the print button). My goal is when the user clicks the button that generates the PDF, it also will print that PDF in the default printer of that computer.  BTW, I'm using Windows for this project and Java JRE7.

Comment: The only thing I coud now is to user jasper reports to generate the pdf file and then it will show to user the pdf and he can now click the print button on that pdf. But what my client wants is to have the pdf preview gone, and print the pdf on printer no pdf preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully accomplished the task by using JPedal, and I can now print pdf file directly onto the printer with the actual size by using the code

```
decodePdf.setPrintPageScalingMode(PrinterOptions.PAGE_SCALING_REDUCE_TO_PRINTER_MARGINS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this blog http://blog.idrsolutions.com/2010/01/printing-pdf-files-from-java/; might helpful for you.

Also you could look for PDFRenderer Java API, might help.

Edit : How to set print attribute - Ref : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jps/spec/attributes.fm4.html

```
PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
aset.add(new Copies(5)); 
aset.add(MediaSize.ISO_A4); 
aset.add(Sides.DUPLEX);
```

Pass this attribute to **`printJob.print(pdfDoc, new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet())`**
Also, you could try getting the supported attribute first and then use accordingly. Please read the above documentation, it is very rich in examples.

Comment: thanks for thius I tried JPedal 30 days trial. I can print pdf files but the problem is I can't seem to set the paper size to "Actual Size" when printing

Comment: Hi Ross, perhaps you want to set attributes to the printing job. I have edited the post for the same. Meanwhile, if this answers helps you, you might want to upvote and accept this answer. Thanks.